# Django, bulk insert of DIFFERENT objects?

Tags: mysql, django, optimization, orm

I currently have a chat system set up like

```
class Link(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Chat(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Message(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   date = models.DateTimeField()
```

There is a chat room that has attached to it multiple messages by different users, and each user is connected to a chat by a link (a link acts as a way to check if a user is "authorized" to be in the chat room)

However, this presents me with the problem that each time a new chat room is created between 2 people, I have to insert 4 objects (2 links, 1 chat, 1 message)

Is there a way to instead do all 4 saves in 1 call instead?

Comment: This is a very much a premature optimization, I find it unlikely that you'll be creating lots of chatrooms at once

Comment: @Sayse yes, a bad habit of mine unfortunately - I will keep what you say in mind (however, Ill keep the question up for pedagogical reasons)

Comment: That's not possible. SQL only allows you to insert into one table at a time.

Comment: Django provides you [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/). Have a look at it, may be that will help you